# Upgrading the SQLite Database of a Production Android App, is this Correct?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, upgrade

As the title says, I have a production Android app with about 1000 installs. I had to make a DB change in SQLite, up to this point the version of the SQLite DB has been set to version "1".

Hopefully I explain the code below sufficiently in the comments, this code resides in my SQLiteOpenHelper Class so the onUpgrade method is part of the Class:

```
// Provides an upgrade path for the DB when the apps version is updated.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // First version of the DB was 1. Logic: each if statement will
        // alter the DB cumulatively based on the version code. So, if the
        // newVersion was version 3, there would be two if statements, one
        // for oldVersion 1 and one for oldVersion 2. oldVersion 2 will
        // contain the logic for upgrading from version 2 to 3, while
        // oldVersion 1 will contain a combination of alter statements
        // allowing the database to upgrade from version 1 directly to
        // version 3.
        if (oldVersion == 1) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE plans ADD COLUMN " + App.CURRENCYCODE
                    + " TEXT");
            Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
            ContentValues content_values = new ContentValues();
            content_values.put(App.CURRENCYCODE, locale.toString());

            db.update(App.DBPLANS, content_values, App.ID + " > ?", new String[] {
                    "0"
            });
        }

        if (oldVersion == 2) {
            // Placeholder for next database upgrade instructions.
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if there are any pitfalls here. So far, it's tested fine, though I'm very concerned about messing up my first DB upgrade. I have a 1,000 users or so, I'd hate to lose them all.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I need to update a database like this, I typically do it with a switch statement where cases fall through to one another, such as:

```
switch (oldVersion) {
    case 1:
        // update to version 2
        // do _not_ break; -- fall through!
    case 2:
        // update to version 3
        // again, do not break;
    case 3:
        // you're already up to date
```

The benefits to this is you do not end up repeating your update statements in multiple if-statements as you continue to change the database, and adding a database update requires only adding a new case statement, not updating multiple blocks of code.

There are sometimes exceptions to this, such as a column added in one version but then deleted in a future one, so you need to pay attention as you go.

Comment: Thanks Mah, but actually, if you read closely, each if statement will hold all the changes to go to the current DB version.

So, if the user is version 1, and the database is version 3, the if statement for version 1 will contain all the logic needed to go to 3. So I think it arrives at the same place as your switch statement. Although, your switch doesn't double up on code.

Comment: Right, this is a better way to go

Comment: I see what you're saying; I'll edit that part out of my answer.

Comment: Your switch is a better way to go, it's the same effect with less code. It's also easier to read. This being said, do I need any breaks at all? I don't think I do.

Comment: I just looked at a (C++) database update I've been maintaining for 17 versions, and there isn't a single break statement in it.

Comment: Official Java answer on the final break "Technically, the final break is not required because flow falls out of the switch statement. Using a break is recommended so that modifying the code is easier and less error prone."